# Get DateTime in two fields

Tags: php, codeigniter

### Getting DateTime

Hi I am not good on programming so don't judge so strong, I want to get date and time from fields.

```
$date_start = $this->input->post('date_start');
$time_start = $this->input->post('time_start');
$date_end = $this->input->post('date_end');
$time_end = $this->input->post('time_end');


$data['start'] = date_format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_start.' '.$time_start);
$data['end'] = date_format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_end.' '.$time_end);
```

### Error

```
date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$data['start'] = date_format(date_create( $date_start.' '.$time_start),"U = Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `date_format` expects an object implementing `DateTimeInterface` as the first argument and the format string as the second argument.

You can create a `DateTime` object from a string with it's factory method [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) also procedurally with `date_create_from_format` documented on the same page.